# Weird issue connecting Bluetooth controller to Windows 10 laptop

Tags: windows, windows-10, bluetooth, game-controller

I had my Nintendo Switch JoyCons pairing just fine with my Windows 10 laptop.

This morning I got a blue screen of death while pairing.

Now when I try to pair them, the "Add Bluetooth Device" window lists two ambiguous "input" devices rather than the usual "JoyCon(R)" or "JoyCon(L)" and when I click on them, it never connects.

The JoyCons still connect to other devices just fine (ie Switch, Android Phone, my wife's laptop)

The JoyCons are not listed in the device manager.

I've searched via google and duckduckgo for a couple hours to find an answer, but the only solution that sort of matched the problem involved plugging in an xbox controller (which I do not have and some users indicated it did not solve the problem for them).

Is there some place where it like remembers the devices that I am not aware of that I can delete and reset things to the way things were?

I've already tried:

- Uninstalling, reinstalling and updating my bluetooth drivers.
- I updated joycon firmware via the switch just to be safe.
- I've tried deleting the joycon device entries from the registry

Screenshot: [Lists "input" instead of "JoyCon(R/L)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuZEY.png)

Many thanks in advance.